# New to Emacs, issue with Melpa

Tags: emacs, melpa

I followed their guide on github and put the following in my init.el file:

```
(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
      (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize) ;; You might already have this line
```

However when I go M-x package-list-packages I either get a Melpa not found error or a 'missing zlib library' error, and it only shows the gnu packages. I've also tried using stable Melpa, to no avail. I'm using windows 10 and set a HOME variable pointing to the directory with the 'init.el' file.

Comment: Missing zlib sounds like the key issue here.

Comment: How do I fix the 'missing zlib' issue though?

Comment: If you can't or don't want to drop Windows, try [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+zlib+missing)?